# What keyboard put the least strain on the epicondyles (elbow tendons)?

Tags: computers, epicondylitis, tendons, ergonomics, repetitive-strain-injury

I wonder what keyboard put the least strain on the epicondyles (elbow tendons).

There exist many keyboards that advertise themselves as being ergonomic, but often fail to provide more details as to which tendon overuse do they prevent, and rarely give any point out to independent, scientific evaluation.

(I am aware that speech recognition software are great for many situations)

---

Here are [some examples of ergonomic keyboards](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=54680.0):

Specific Keyboards:

- Kinesis Advantage (Cherry Brown/Red))
- Maltron (Cherry Black)
- Ergodox (Cherry) [example](http://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=22780.msg428504#msg428504)
- Truly Ergonomic (Cherry)
- µTron (Topre)
- Goldtouch (Rubber Dome)
- Kinesis Freestyle (Rubber Dome)
- MS Ergo/Sculpt

[Keyboards in Development](http://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=54858.0)

- Ergoduck
- Matias Ergo Pro (Alps)
- Keyboard.IO
- CombiMouse
- Nexus

Extinct Keyboards:

- [Datahand (Optical/Magnetic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataHand) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rzFqEqzhmA))
- IBM M15 (Buckling Spring)
- Cherry MX5000 (Cherry Brown/Black)
- Kinesis Evolution (Alps)

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.